# Do CSS properties apply to continuously nested tags of the same type?

Tags: html, css

I apologize for the confusion my question may cause, I couldn't find an efficient way to word it!

Basically, if I have some HTML code like this:

```
<div class="style">
    <div>
        <div>
            <p>Hello world!</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And some CSS like this:

```
.style div{
    background-color: red;
}
```

Will the `background-color` property apply to just the first-tier nested `div` *or* the same, as well as the nested `div` inside of that?

Comment: All elements matching that selector nested inside of `.style` - so, yes, all `div`s

Comment: Read about [CSS Combinators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors#Combinators). Right now you're using the Descendant combinator.

Comment: Thank you! Please can you post that as an answer so I can mark as solved? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ruleset will apply to all elements which match the selector.

The selector is `.style div`: "Every element of the type `div` which is a descendant of any element that is a member of the class `style`.

In your HTML, that is every div element except the outermost one.